# Use lorentz to wrap my SmartPy contract to multisig failed

Tags: node, smartpy

I write a simple contract at smarty ide, [link](https://smartpy.io/demo/index.html?code=eJxdkM0KwjAQhO@FvsPSU4oS8CoUBMFX8BiWJsVA80N2pfTtTSxp0T3kMN_sDBvrYkgM5DBxXAEJKLZN24wzEsHT8ksnXARFeQ@eE47cX9sG8mgzgVLWW1ZKkJmncyVliiALFP0mbu8tB5mcs6oYrOcjadmbShJETOjoJzBKMl6LjUgO1STRhbfn_rC2TalBrRUbYuHRGRige9hEDEXqsrmUfnEtodF4TDZka94uSFWp3jBeMtz_pP_bOw3Z8AF9MmNJ).
And then I use [lorentz-contract](https://github.com/tqtezos/lorentz-contract-param) to wrap it to multi sig contract, but I meet an error:
[image]

Comment: Please link to what you mean by this lorentz-contract wrapper. It is unclear without context what you are referring to and what is the source of the tool you are using

Comment: It seems like the issue is that the lorentz-wrapper does not recognize the DIG instructions. Try opening an issue in their repo: https://github.com/tqtezos/lorentz-contract-param

Answer (score 2):

As already said elsewhere, DIG has been added several months ago in Michelson. Your Lorentz script is extremely outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The Multisig contract and wrapper, including an updated multisig wrapper, have been migrated from `lorentz-contract-param` to [lorentz-contract-multisig](https://github.com/tqtezos/lorentz-contract-multisig).